# slim php $stmt->get_result() to $stmt->bind_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

my question is how to translate get_result() to bind_result()

here is my index.php 
//

```
$app->get('/tasks', 'authenticate', function() {
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // fetching all user tasks
        $result = $db->getAllUserTasks($user_id);

        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["tasks"] = array();

        // looping through result and preparing tasks array
        while ($task = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp["id"] = $task["id"];
            $tmp["task"] = $task["task"];
            $tmp["status"] = $task["status"];
            $tmp["createdAt"] = $task["created_at"];
            array_push($response["tasks"], $tmp);
        }

        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    });
```

//

here is the dbhandler.php

```
 public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tasks = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;
}
```

i am having all sorts of trouble trying to convert it to use bind_result() instead of get_result(), can some please give me some advice

thank you advance

Jason

here is my approach trying to convert it without luck please point out the problem thanks

index.php
///

```
$app->get('/companies', 'authenticate', function() {
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // fetching all user tasks
        $result = $db->getAllUserCompanies($user_id);

        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["companies"] = array();
        $companies = array();
        while ($companies = $result->fetch()) {
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp["CompanyID"] = $companies["CompanyID"];
            $tmp["UserID"] = $companies["UserID"];
            $tmp["CompanyName"] = $companies["CompanyName"];
            $tmp["CompanyAddress"] = $companies["CompanyAddress"];
            $tmp["CompanyCity"] = $companies["CompanyCity"];
            $tmp["CompanyIndustry"] = $companies["CompanyIndustry"];
            $tmp["CompanyContact"] = $companies["CompanyContact"];
            $tmp["CompanyNotes"] = $companies["CompanyNotes"];
            $tmp["CreatedDate"] = $companies["CreatedDate"];
            $tmp["UpdatedTime"] = $companies["UpdatedTime"];
            $tmp["UpdatedBy"] = $companies["UpdatedBy"];
            array_push($response["companies"], $tmp); 

        echoRespnse(200, $response); 
     }
    });
```

dbhealper.php
//

```
public function getAllUserCompanies($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyID, UserID, CompanyName, CompanyAddress, CompanyCity, CompanyIndustry, CompanyContact, CompanyNotes, CreatedDate, UpdatedTime, UpdatedBy FROM company WHERE UserID = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        //if ($stmt->execute()) {
        ($stmt->execute());
        $companies = array();
        $companies = $stmt->bind_result($CompanyID, $UserID, $CompanyName, $CompanyAddress, $CompanyCity, $CompanyIndustry, $CompanyContact, $CompanyNotes, $CreatedDate, $UpdatedTime, $UpdatedBy);
        $stmt->close();
        return $companies;
}
```

Comment: Can you also show how are you trying to write for bind_result() and  bind_result() Doesn't work with SQL query that use * Just use the column names and I believe it is gonna work for you. \

Answer (score 1):

*dbhealper.php //*

You can try this

```
public function getAllUserCompanies($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyID, UserID, CompanyName, CompanyAddress, CompanyCity, CompanyIndustry, CompanyContact, CompanyNotes, CreatedDate, UpdatedTime, UpdatedBy FROM company WHERE UserID = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        /* Store the result (to get properties) */
        $stmt->store_result();

        /* Get the number of rows */
        $num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;

        /* Bind the result to variables */
        $companies = $stmt->bind_result($CompanyID, $UserID, $CompanyName, $CompanyAddress, $CompanyCity, $CompanyIndustry, $CompanyContact, $CompanyNotes, $CreatedDate, $UpdatedTime, $UpdatedBy);
    return $companies;
        /* free results */
        $stmt->free_result();
}
```

if you look there is no much changes which has been done to it but to store the results I have added a line after `$stmt->execute();` `$stmt->store_result();`

Comment: this still gives the Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in cheers

Comment: May be we can try this 

`$stmt->bind_result($CompanyID, $UserID, $CompanyName, $CompanyAddress, $CompanyCity, $CompanyIndustry, $CompanyContact, $CompanyNotes, $CreatedDate, $UpdatedTime, $UpdatedBy);

return $stmt->fetch();`

Comment: if do the flect() in the datahandler.php how would the loop work in the index.php cheers

Comment: while ($db->getAllUserCompanies($user_id)) {

Comment: still no luck, this thing is driving me crazy been on it since friday, still can't find a solution to fix a simple issue.. any other suggestions would be very helpful cheers

Comment: did u tried writing the code in index.php and not use the function at all. See if it works

Answer (score 1):

If your getting an error with $stmt->get_result, it may be because of this:
it works only with mysqlnd driver (https://www.php.net/manual/en/m.... Solve it by using this:
DbHandler.php

```
/**
 * Fetching all user tasks
 * @param String $user_id id of the user
 */
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $task, $status, $created_at);
    $tasks = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $id;
        $tmp["task"] = $task;
        $tmp["status"] = $status;
        $tmp["createdAt"] = $created_at;
        array_push($tasks, $tmp);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;
}
```

and in index.php:

```
/**
 * Fetching all user tasks
 * @param String $user_id id of the user
 */
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $task, $status, $created_at);
    $tasks = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp["id"] = $id;
        $tmp["task"] = $task;
        $tmp["status"] = $status;
        $tmp["createdAt"] = $created_at;
        array_push($tasks, $tmp);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $tasks;
}
```

I am guessing the code sample is from http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/

Answer (score 0):

I advise against using `get_result()` in any php code, simply because it requires `mysqlnd` to be installed, and is not supported in `libmysql`, which is the most common libary used for interfacing with mysql from php. instead, `fetch()` should be used to create an array of rows from the result set, or `bind_result()` for situations where you are only returning 1 row.

```
public function getAllUserTasks($user_id) {
    $tasks = [];
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {
         while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $tasks[] = $row;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    return $tasks;
}
```

**EDIT**

to use it index.php

```
$app->get('/companies', 'authenticate', function() {
    global $user_id;
    $db = new DbHandler();

    // fetching all user tasks
    $response = $db->getAllUserCompanies($user_id);
    if(!empty($response))
    {
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    }else{
        //handle your error
    }
});
```

Comment: this dbhandler.php looks different approach how would the index.php would look like if we go by your dbhander.php cheers

Comment: just replace the damn function. easy as pie.

Comment: the same exact way as before. it returns an array of results just as it did in the original.

Comment: i get this Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in error in the index.php page

Comment: if it says `BOOL(FALSE)` it means there's an error in your query. try running it from the commandline or phpmyadmin. if it says `(NULL)` check your db connection.

Comment: @Jasonsti nope, you have a typo in your query. missing `,` before `ut`

Comment: This is not a valid query: `SELECT t.* FROM tasks t, user_tasks ut WHERE t.id = ut.task_id AND ut.user_id = ?` Fix it.

Comment: sorry i am not using that query here is what i am using, and there is nothing wrong with the query-- "$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT CompanyID, UserID, CompanyName, CompanyAddress, CompanyCity, CompanyIndustry, CompanyContact, CompanyNotes, CreatedDate, UpdatedTime, UpdatedBy FROM company WHERE UserID = ?");"

Comment: I already told you there is either a problem with your query or with your connection.

Comment: cheers for that, i get the code 200 alright, without any data, sorry for the such a dumb question do i have to construct the data in the datahandler.php ie. $tasks[] = $row; part.. thanks alot you been great.. cheers

Comment: are you sure there is no data? try print_r($response, false);

Comment: Nope still no luck doing print_r

Comment: you need to post all of your applicable code then. otherwise were stumbling in the dark here.

Comment: got it working but only returns 1 result of arrays, i have more than one records in the database, how would i loop it can i use fetchAll instead

Comment: If you got it working then update your question and include an answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense here i tried to clean it up some. I'm not sure quite how the ternary statement got in there. AFAICT, it should work. I haven't written php in a while but i used `mysqli->fetch()` plenty of times in the past.